# multi step from -Data collected

Tags: forms, multi-step, data-collection

I am using contact form 7 multi-step forms. Total of 3 forms. When I get the final email it does not have all of the data from all of the forms only the last form after submitting. What am I doing wrong?... the multi- step functions are working and re directing properly just not collecting all of the data. It seems like this would be something easy to fix but I cant figure it out.
Thank you kindly!

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Overflow! Would it be possible for you to add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question? As it stands I don't think we have enough information to help you with this.

Comment: My apologies I don’t know what you are asking for. I am not a programmer just trying to get my WP site to function properly. Again sorry if this is really dumbed down or maybe I am not asking in a way to get true help. 
I used contact form 7 to create forms on my website. I downloaded a plug-in for contact form 7 to create multi step forms to collect data on 3 separate pages. When I submit on the final page the email that is sent to me does not have the data from all of the forms. It only has the data form the last form on the submit page. So it’s not collecting from the two pages prior. TKS!